# Do not indirectly expose methods with link demands

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop

I don't know how to fix my FxCop problem.

This is my interested function

```
  public void WriteLine(int eventNumber, string message,  params object[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            rwl.WaitOne();
            try
            {

                        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + "\t\t" + eventNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + "\t" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name + "\t" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + "\t" + tID + " \t " + message, args);                   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Cannot write to file " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                rwl.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)
        {
        }
    }
```

This is the error:
CriticalError, Certainty 33, for DoNotIndirectlyExposeMethodsWithLinkDemands
  Help         : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182303(VS.100).aspx
 Info         : "Do not wrap a method protected by a LinkDemand with 
                   a method that does not perform a security check. A 
                   LinkDemand checks the permissions of the immediate 
                   caller rather than checking the permissions of all 
                   callers in the call stack. In this case, the permissions 
                   of the wrapper method will be checked. If the wrapper 
                   method does not, itself, check the permissions of callers 
                   higher in the call stack, malicious code might be able 
                   to execute the wrapped function even though it lacks 
                   permission to do so."

Comment: What is `rwl`? Check the source of `rwl.ReleaseMutex` and `rwl.WaitOne` (and possibly `sw.WriteLine` for their security relevant attributes. You need to apply those attributes to your `WriteLine` method. I can't explain the mechanism in detail, but this way the callers of your method are security-checked, which is what these `LinkDemand` attributes want. You'll have to do this all the way up the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Is `rwl` a [Mutex][1]?  If so, the class is decorated with a [HostProtectionAttribute][2] that creates a link demand for HostProtectionPermission, which is presumably what is causing rule CA2122 to fire.

That said, FxCop has specifically excluded HostProtectionPermission from consideration in rule CA2122 since at least FxCop 10.0 (because it's not really a security concern), so it seems a bit odd that you are seeing this rule violation.  If you're using an older version of FxCop, and you're quite sure that it is a HostProtectionAttribute that is causing the problem, it would seem quite safe to suppress the violation.  Otherwise, could you please provide some more detail (FxCop version, Visual Studio version, target framework version, `sw` and `rwl` types) so that the cause of the violation might be more easily identified?

Comment: This is the problem : calls into 'Process.GetCurrentProcess()' 
                   which has a LinkDemand. By making this call, 'Process.GetCurrentProcess()
                   ' is indirectly exposed to user code. Review the following 
                   call stack that might expose a way to circumvent security 
                   protection

Comment: Sorry, I didn't scroll far enough to the right to see the `Process` use.  There are several options for addressing this, but the best option would depend on a few things.  Which version of the .NET framework are you targeting?  Also, is your assembly decorated with any of the following attributes: `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers`, `SecurityRules`, `SecurityCritical`, or `SecurityTransparent`?  If any of these attributes are present, do you know why they were added?